# Create an interface that fits the XKCD Types

Tags: code-golf

[image]

> colors.rgb("blue") yields "#0000FF". colors.rgb("yellowish blue") yields NaN. colors.sort() yields "rainbow"

Using the rules set out in the image and its title text (quoted here), create a program that accepts all the given input and displays the appropriate output.

- Input can be taken with stdin or nearest equivalent. There should be a line like `[n]>` on which to type it, and `n` increases by 1 each command. It should start at 1.
- The result should be displayed using stdout or nearest equivalent. There should be a `=>` on each line of output.

All 13 conditions, plus the 3 in the title (quoted) must work.

This is code golf, so shortest answer wins.

Comment: How general should the interface be? For instance, does the floor function have to work for any provided float or can we assume it will only ever be passed `10.5`?

Comment: Are the > for the output aligned with the > for the input, as n grows and the input > moves farther to the right?

Comment: This comic can potentially be interpreted in several ways. Could you provide a list of what *specific* types and operations we need to implement?

Comment: @dohaqatar7 any interpretation is acceptable unless stated otherwise. Only the test cases have to match.

Comment: @dohaqatar7 only 10.5 - I have no idea what 3+5 is :)

Comment: @Sparr it would be cool, but is optional.

Comment: @Sparr if it outputs the test cases, you're fine.

Comment: @Tim the alignment in the test cases is unclear. it appears to show `[1] >` and `[10] >` being the same width, and all that implies for the `= >` lines below them.

Comment: [tag:code-golf] questions require a strict specification.  *"any interpretation is acceptable"* is far too fuzzy, IMO.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma that's not what I said - I said if it outputs the above it's fine.

Comment: Why should `n` increase by 1? That's not what the comic does... ;-)

Comment: To be brutally honest, I think that this is way too underspecified as we do not know how each example reacts for any input. In the end this broils down to a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] variant.

Comment: @BetaDecay Then don't answer it?

Comment: @WolframH It is - but he made 2 = 4 in command 11 so it displays 14 not 12.

Comment: @Tim LOL, thanks for clearing that up :-)

Comment: @Tim I don't see how `2+2` means 2 should become 4. Yes, the output of command 14 shows that it now is, but still, I don't get it.

Comment: @MrLister I think it's 2 is 2 then he +2 to it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Python 3, <strike>700 698 697 689 683 639</strike> 611

Tabs as indentation.

```
from ast import*
E=literal_eval
O='=>%s\n'
P=print
I=int
def Q(a):P(O%a)
def W(a):Q('"%s"'%str(a))
def gb(a):W(_ if'y'in a else'#0000FF')
def t():W('rainbow')
def FLOOR(n):P(O%'|'*3+(O%'|{:_^10}').format(n))
def RANGE(*a):Q([('"','!',' ','!','"'),(1,4,3,4,5)][len(a)])
c=0
while 1:
    try:
        c+=1;A,*B=input('[%d]>'%c).split('+')
        if not A:W(c+I(B[0]))
        elif A=='""':Q("'\"+\"'")
        elif B:
            A=E(A);B=E(B[0])
            if A==B:Q('DONE')
            elif type(A)==list:Q(A[-1]==B-1)
            elif type(B)==list:W([I(A)])
            else:W(A+I(B))
        else:eval(A.lstrip('colrs.'))
    except:Q('Na'+['N','P','N.%s13'%('0'*13)][('-'in A)+len(B)])
```

*Since this uses a bare Except you can't Ctrl-C it. Ctrl-Z and kill %% work though*

Some of the conditions are generalized and others will only work with exact input.

1. `A+"B"` will work with any A and B not just when `A == B`
2. `"A"+[]` will work for any A that can be converted to an int (Includes hex and binary strings e.g 0xff and 0b01010)
3. `(A/0)` will work for any A, Eval Causes `DivideByZeroError` which is handled in the except
4. `(A/0)+B` will work with any A or B. `literal_eval` (E) raises an error.
5. `""+""` only works for the + sign. Anything else will print NaN, NaP or NaN.00...
6. `[A, B, C]+D` works by checking that `D == C+1` so will work for any length of list and any numbers.
7. ^^
8. `2/(2-(3/2+1/2))`, Anything that fails to parse that has `-` with a `+` somewhere after it will output NaN.000...13
9. `RANGE(" ")` Hardcoded
10. `+A` will work for any A. Ouputs `"current_line_number+A"`
11. `A+A` works for any A as long as they are the same and are bulitin python types
12. `RANGE(1,5)` Hardcoded.
13. `FLOOR(A)` works for any A.
14. `colors.rgb("blue")` The lstrip in eval turns this in `gb("blue")` which has a hardcoded response.
15. `colors.rgb("yellowish blue")` The lstrip in eval turns this in `gb("yellowish blue")` which attempts to use a non existent variable if `y` is present in the arguement causing an error which the except turns into NaN
16. `colors.sort()` The lstrip turns this into `t()` which has a hardcoded response.

[image]

[image]

*Brainsteel pointed out an error in my assumption for rule 10.*

[image]

Comment: Very neat. I think, on #10, it seems that the "+A" is intended to output the *line number* + A, rather than just prepending 1.

Comment: Ahh yes, obvious now that its pointed out. Well that means that int will be better as a single letter function. Might save a byte or two.

Comment: re #9: `RANGE(" ")` is a range of characters from the double quote character \x22 to the space character \x20 and back.

Comment: re the jump: because Randall set `2` to `4` in line 11, 2 is now 4 and 12 is now 14. This also applies to line numbers.

Comment: You could save some bytes by using space, tab and tab + space for your indentation.

Comment: I believe `RANGE(s) == (s, chr(ord(s)+1))*2` or similar.

Comment: `list` is shorter than `T([])`.

Answer (score 15):

## Python, 1110 bytes

Operator overloading isn't evil, right??

```
from re import*
class V(str):
 def __add__(s,r):return s[:-1]+chr(ord(s[-1])+r)
class S(str):
 def __str__(s):return "'"+s+"'"if '"'in s else'"'+s+'"'
 def __repr__(s):return str(s)
 def __add__(s,r):s=str(s)[1:-1];return S('['+s+']'if type(r)==L else '"+"' if(s,r)==('','')else s+r)
class I(int):
 def __add__(s,r):return type(r)(int(s)+int(r))if s!=r else V('DONE')
 def __div__(s,r):return N if r==0 else int(s)/int(r)
 def __pos__(s):return s+c*10
 def __mul__(s,r):return V('NaN.'+'0'*13+'13')if r==1 else int(s)*int(r)
class L(list):
 def __add__(s,r):return V(str(r==s[-1]+1).upper())
def RANGE(a,b=0):return 2*(a,S(chr(ord(a)+1)))if b==0 else tuple([a]+[b-1,a+2]*((b-a)/4)+[b-1,b])
def FLOOR(n):return V('|\n|\n|\n|___%s___'%n)
def colorsrgb(c):
 m={'blue':V('#0000FF')}
 return m.get(c,N)
def colorssort():return V('rainbow')
N=V('NaN')
c=1
while True:
 try:l=raw_input('[%d] >'%c)
 except:break
 l=sub(r'(?<!"|\.)(\d+)(?!\.|\d)',r'I(\1)',l)
 l=sub(r'"(.*?)"',r'S("\1")',l)
 l=sub(r'\[(.*?)\]',r'L([\1])',l)
 l=sub(r'/\(','*(',l)
 l=sub('s\.','s',l)
 for x in str(eval(l)).split('\n'):print ' =',x
 c+=1
```

My goal wasn't as much winning (obviously) as it is making it as generic as possible. Very little is hardcoded. Try stuff like `RANGE(10)`, `9*1`, and `RANGE("A")`, `(2/0)+14`, and `"123"` for fun results!

Here's a sample session:

```
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$ python xktp.py
[1] >ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$ python xktp.py
[1] >1+1
 = DONE
[2] >2+"2"
 = "4"
[3] >"2"+2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xktp.py", line 31, in <module>
    for x in str(eval(l)).split('\n'):print ' =',x
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xktp.py", line 7, in __add__
    def __add__(s,r):s=str(s)[1:-1];return S('['+s+']'if type(r)==L else '"+"' if(s,r)==('','')else s+r)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'I' objects
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$ python xktp.py
[1] >ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$ python xktp.py
[1] >2+"2"
 = "4"
[2] >"2"+[]
 = "[2]"
[3] >"2"+[1, 2, 3]
 = "[2]"
[4] >(2/0)
 = NaN
[5] >(2/0)+2
 = NaP
[6] >(2/0)+14
 = Na\
[7] >""+""
 = '"+"'
[8] >[1,2,3]+2
 = FALSE
[9] >[1,2,3]+4
 = TRUE
[10] >[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]+9
 = FALSE
[11] >[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]+8
 = TRUE
[12] >2/(2-(3/2+1/2))
 = NaN.000000000000013
[13] >9*1
 = NaN.000000000000013
[14] >RANGE(" ")
 = (" ", "!", " ", "!")
[15] >RANGE("2")
 = ("2", "3", "2", "3")
[16] >RANGE(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xktp.py", line 31, in <module>
    for x in str(eval(l)).split('\n'):print ' =',x
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xktp.py", line 15, in RANGE
    def RANGE(a,b=0):return 2*(a,S(chr(ord(a)+1)))if b==0 else tuple([a]+[b-1,a+2]*((b-a)/4)+[b-1,b])
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but I found
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$ python xktp.py
[1] >ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$ # oops
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$ python xktp.py
[1] >RANGE("2")
 = ("2", "3", "2", "3")
[2] >RANGE(2*1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xktp.py", line 31, in <module>
    for x in str(eval(l)).split('\n'):print ' =',x
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xktp.py", line 15, in RANGE
    def RANGE(a,b=0):return 2*(a,S(chr(ord(a)+1)))if b==0 else tuple([a]+[b-1,a+2]*((b-a)/4)+[b-1,b])
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 19 found
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$ python xktp.py # oops again
[1] >RANGE(1,20)
 = (1, 19, 3, 19, 3, 19, 3, 19, 3, 19, 20)
[2] >RANGE(1,5)
 = (1, 4, 3, 4, 5)
[3] >RANGE(10,20)
 = (10, 19, 12, 19, 12, 19, 20)
[4] >RANGE(10,200)
 = (10, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 12, 199, 200)
[5] >+2
 = 52
[6] >+"99"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xktp.py", line 31, in <module>
    for x in str(eval(l)).split('\n'):print ' =',x
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'S'
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$ python xktp.py # oops again and again!
[1] >FLOOR(200)
 = |
 = |
 = |
 = |___200___
[2] >2+2
 = DONE
[3] >3+#
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xktp.py", line 31, in <module>
    for x in str(eval(l)).split('\n'):print ' =',x
  File "<string>", line 1
    I(3)+#
         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$ python xktp.py
[1] >3+3
 = DONE
[2] >ryan@DevPC-LX:~/golf/xktp$
```

Answer (score 6):

## C, 412 bytes

This is basically hardcoded, but all the other answers so far were missing something...

```
i;char b[99];main(){for(;;){printf("[%d]>",abs(++i));gets(b);i-=b[2]==50?26:0;printf("=>");puts(*b==82?b[6]==34?"('\"',\"!\",\" \",\"!\",'\"')":"(1,4,3,4,5)":*b==70?"|\n=>|\n=>|\n=>|___10.5___":*b==43?"12":*b==91?b[8]==50?"FALSE":"TRUE":*b==34?b[1]==34?"'\"+\"'":"\"[2]\"":*b==40?b[5]==43?"NaP":"NaN":*b==99?b[7]=='s'?"rainbow":b[12]==98?"#0000FF":"NaN":b[1]==43?b[2]==34?"\"4\"":"DONE":"NaN.000000000000013");}}
```

Output:

```
[1]>2+"2"
=>"4"
[2]>"2"+[]
=>"[2]"
[3]>(2/0)
=>NaN
[4]>(2/0)+2
=>NaP
[5]>""+""
=>'"+"'
[6]>[1,2,3]+2
=>FALSE
[7]>[1,2,3]+4
=>TRUE
[8]>2/(2-(3/2+1/2))
=>NaN.000000000000013
[9]>RANGE(" ")
=>('"',"!"," ","!",'"')
[10]>+2
=>12
[11]>2+2
=>DONE
[14]>RANGE(1,5)
=>(1,4,3,4,5)
[13]>FLOOR(10.5)
=>|
=>|
=>|
=>|___10.5___
```

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, 298

Everything is hardcoded, but the input is turned into a number that is then converted to a string and looked up in a large string that contains all these numbers followed by their answers.

```
B="""53"#0000FF"~62DONE~43NaN.000000000000013~25(1,4,3,4,5)~26"rainbow"~49"4"~21"[2]"~29FALSE~15|*|*|*|___10.5___~17'"+"'~1212~60('"',"!"," ","!",'"')~24NaN~31TRUE~64NaN~76NaP"""
i=0
while 1:i+=1;s=input("[%s]>"%i);print("=>"+B[B.find(str(sum(map(ord,s))%81))+2:].split("~")[0].replace("*","\n=>"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <strike>542</strike> 484 bytes

Since there was no mention of absolute hardcoding here's my solution.

```
a={'2+"2"':'"4"','"2"+[]':'"[2]"',"(2/0)":"NaN","(2/0)+2":"NaP",'""+""':"'\"+\"'","[1,2,3]+2":"FALSE","[1,2,3]+4":"TRUE","2/(2-(3/2+1/2))":"NaN.000000000000013",'RANGE(" ")':'(\'"\',"!"," ","!",\'"\')',"+2":"12","2+2":"DONE","RANGE(1,5)":"(1,4,3,4,5)","FLOOR(10.5)":"|\n|\n|\n|___10.5___",'colors.rgb("blue")':'"#0000FF"','colors.rgb("yellowish blue")':"NaN","colors.sort()":'"rainbow"'}
i=1
while 1:b=a[input("[%i]>"%i).replace("\t","")].split("\n");print("=> "+"\n=> ".join(b));i+=1
```

Comment: Hardcoding is fine, but I think the [loopholes that are forbidden by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default. :P

Comment: @ThomasKwa I don't see anything here that is a forbidden loophole. Is there?

Comment: Everything looks compliant to me. I earlier assumed you were exploiting a loophole because you said there was "no mention of [...] standard loopholes".

Comment: I think it's creative, but not an answer. The question clearly talks about input and output: *"create a program that accepts all the given input and displays the appropriate output"*

Comment: You can save a good amount by using both quotes. `"2+\"2\""` becomes `'2+"2"'`. Importing count could also be removed if you add a counter variable.